# Calculation of age using Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am creating an App using Xcode and I need to validate the age of the users. I am a newbie and I'm slightly struggling with Objective-C.

I've used a UITextField to obtain the input from the user in the format DD/MM/YYYY. I also know how to obtain the present date using NSDate and to use the NSDateFormatter. My problem arises when I need to compare the two years or two dates.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];

 int PresentYear = (int)[dateString substringToIndex:-4];
int InputYear = (int)[DOB.text substringToIndex:-4];

if(PresentYear-InputYear<18)
```

I cannot seem to explicitly convert it to an integer. IS there any other way of doing this?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got it all backwards.

Convert the input date to an `NSDate`. Compare that with `[NSDate date]`. It's most easy to do so by asking a calendar* (`currentCalendar` will do) for the `NSDateComponents` that describe the difference between the dates. Check the `year` property on that.

Don't muck about writing your own little string parsing when that's exactly what `NSDateFormatter` provides for you.

(*) it doesn't really matter with years, as the calendars all basically agree. But if you were going to get difference in, say, months then it would — e.g. the Chinese calendar has 13 months in a leap year.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

unsigned units = NSCalendarUnitYear| NSCalendarUnitMonth| NSCalendarUnitDay;

NSDateComponents* components = [calendar components:units fromDate:today];
NSInteger year = [components year];
```

This will get year from today.

```
NSInteger inputYear = [[dateString substringFromIndex:6] integerValue];
```

This will get year from input string.

Comment: Thanks for that ! But what about my input from the user?

Comment: use [[dateString substringFromIndex:6] integerValue]